# npm install everything except named package

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

An extract from my Dockerfile which builds my Angular app:

```
# Do other stuff
RUN npm install
# next line executes ng build --prod
RUN npm run build:prod
```

The `npm install` is for build purposes. Some of the packages in devDependencies - particularly cypress - take ages to install and are not needed for the build. However, some packages in devDependencies are needed.

Can I, for example, do an npm install everything except cypress?

`npm install --only=prod` is not an option because some devDependencies are needed.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion. Use [install-subset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-subset), and can be installed globally with `npm install -g install-subset`

To use it, you build inclusion lists and exclusion lists for named installation subsets in your `package.json` like this:

```
"subsets": {
    "build": {
        "include": [
            "babel-cli",
            "dotenv"
        ]
    },
    "test": {
        "exclude": [
            "eslint",
            "lint-rules",
            "prettier"
        ]
    }
}
```

Then run `install-subset test`

This will temporarily rewrite your package.json to not install those packages excluded, then restore it (very similar to how lerna operates), which depending on the packages can save a lot of time and bandwidth.

Comment: never like using packages that aren't well maintained or popular - however, in this case I may make an exception - many thanks :) although other ideas are welcome